# Access: Run time error 424 with ActiveWorkbook.path

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to open the directory that contains my Access database using this code

```
Dim path As String
path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"
Shell "cmd /C start """" /max """ & path & """", vbHide
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32359117/5411493) by @AnorZaken.

The second line however raises a run time error "424 object required".
When I use some static path (i.e. `path = "C:\"`) everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveWorkbook` is for Excel.  In Access, use `CurrentProject`

```
'path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"
path = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
```