# Using opened windows explorer and selecting a file to upload a file on internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, windows-explorer

I am trying to upload a large number of documents to a document upload/creation in SharePoint. I am using VBA to navigate to the website, hit the upload buttons. It pulls up the file explorer. My question is, how can I navigate to the folder and select a specific file?

```
Sub uploader()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") ' creates new instance of internet explorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate ("restricted website, redacted for this post")

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readystate = 4 ' waits until ready

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default btn-sm")(1).Click ' clicks upload doc button
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ms-dlgFrame")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OpenWithExplorerLink").Click ' clicks upload, opens file explorer
    'here i need it to navigate down the path and select the file, using the windows explorer that was just opened.
End Sub
```

I don't want it to pull up a new file explorer. Is it possible to select a file to upload from the already opened explorer?

Comment: I think it's impossible to select the file from the existing windows explorer. I find [an article](https://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_uploadvbaie/) about automated file upload using IE, but it seems not work in my test. I also tried other ways and failed. You can use [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205719/how-to-open-a-folder-in-windows-explorer-from-vba/11205721#11205721) in the thread to open a file in windows explorer. And I think selenium is a workaround for automating IE.

Comment: ok, thanks, I appreciate your answer. @YuZhou