# Unable to correctly open a network drive from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code set up so that when the macro is run, a folder is created on a network drive, and then should open the created folder. However, it will only ever open the documents folder instead.

If I change the code to the below it correctly opens the folder in question (in this case the `Applications` folder) - how can I get it to open the newly created one instead?

```
If .Value = "Section 50" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
    dirName = Cells(4, i).Values
    MkDir ("\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Section 50\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")")
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Section 50\Applications 2019-20\", vbNormalFocus)
```

This code is part of a larger script so I've just shown the necessary section.

```
If .Value = "Section 50" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
    dirName = Cells(4, i).Values
    MkDir ("\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Section 50\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")")
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Section 50\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Try this  `Call Shell(chr(34) & "explorer.exe".... ")" & chr(34), vbNormalFocus)` What we are doing is padding the spaces in the path

Comment: To understand it... `Dim sPath as String` and then `sPath = "\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Section 50\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")"` and finally `Call Shell(chr(34) & "explorer.exe" & " " & sPath & chr(34), vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: Your shell command fails on blanks in path! It has to be surounded by double-quotes, what needs doubled double-quotes`""`(or concat an Chr(34) for better readability) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11205721/9439330. Or use [Workbook.FollowHyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.followhyperlink) as alternative.

Comment: @SiddharthRout same issue unfortunately! Still just opens my documents folder.

Comment: @SiddharthRout path needs to be quoted seperate to  be interpreted as one argument.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I have the same line of code running on a different network drive and it all works perfectly, so not sure why it's the case here. All the paths are correct.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Code there is `If .Value = "Mobile Plant" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
                
                dirName = Cells(4, i).Values
         MkDir ("\\wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\groups\operational_services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")")
         Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "\\wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\groups\operational_services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")", vbNormalFocus)
                `

Comment: OK its the`&`that causes the trouble! But additional quotes around path solves this. To debug this. use a variable for the path and debug.print it. then try the result path on a commandline.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher why would the exact same code not run as expected when all that's changed is the path? They both use the same end section of `& Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")", vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: It's the **&** in the path! Try on commandline! Always surround paths with quotes on commandline, as the usually fail on blanks too (surprisingly not with explorer).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the commandline?

Comment: Start a command line (cmd.exe) and use the string passed to the`Shell`function there, what should create same results  There you can play with quoting and paths containing an ampersand or not:.

Comment: I've found the issue - I had tried additional quotes around the path so it was `Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & ""\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")"", vbNormalFocus)` , but I actually needed another set of double quotes around it.

Comment: See my first comment. To create a duoble-quote inside a string you need to double it (escape). E.g.: `StringWithOneDoubleQuote = """"`would show `" `as the first and the last d-quotes are the string-literal delimiters and the second one escapes the third that is displayed at the end. As this is confusing use `StringWithOneDoubleQuote = "" & Chr(34) & ""`where the Chr function returns a d-quote to the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ampersands(**&**) in your folders path and don't [escape them with`^` or double-quotes](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) it makes the command-line think that a new command is following the ampersand as it is used to [run multiple commands on a single line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Your documents folder is opened because`explorer \\`is a [explorer command-line switch](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html).

For testing you can open a command-line (cmd.exe) and try:

```
explorer.exe \\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\
```

what should show`command Transport not found`as the ampersand concats multiple commands and the shell thinks`Transport`is the next one, but didn't find it.

Now try

```
explorer.exe "\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\"
```

or

```
explorer.exe \\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic ^& Transport\
```

Both commands are working now as the ampersand is escaped.

As alternative you can use [Workbook.FollowHyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.followhyperlink) what escapes the ampersand automatic. Try

```vb
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\"
```