# Opening subfolder with variable name

Tags: excel, vba, subdirectory

I would like to find an efficient way to open a subfolder with a variable name which I enter in Excel.

For example, I would like to enter the subfolder name "AB 123456" in a cell in Excel and then it should search the network folder "J:\Projects" which has many subfolders which in its turn again has subfolders. These subfolders again have subfolders, etc.

Of course I could go to the subfolder by always clicking, but it would be more efficient if it opens when entering the subfolder's name.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What does "open a subfolder" mean in this situation? Open the folder in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205719/how-to-open-a-folder-in-windows-explorer-from-vba), but change file path to `var = Range("A1").Value`

Don't know how to search for sub-subfolders tho

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub Open_Folder()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim FullPath As String
    
    FolderName = Range("A1").Value

    FolderPath = "J:\Projects\"
    FullPath = FolderPath & FolderName
    
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & FullPath, vbNormalFocus)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The folder in question could be a subfolder of another folder so recursive search is required to locate the folder before attempting to open it.